# Typescript get type of only callable/executable members

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, types, type-conversion, typescript-generics

I have a class with mixed member types, fields and methods (ex. `MyClass` below).
I am trying to have a command created that calls a function and is able to execute it while keeping `this` context.

The code below works if I use a class that has no fields in it, only callable members ( ex. if i comment out `public field: number = 1;`)  This works fine, good type sense, errors if class method does not exist, errors if bad params. but it kind of does not like it when i pass a class that has non-callable members.
Maybe you guys have a solution for that?

[TS playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUDeBYAUNawD2AdhAC4BOArsMXqQBQCU0qAvljm9APSfQAO5AIxABLYNABmwgKYgAJgC5oBcgFsBU0tAC80AIwBuLB35DRfUsILFYUqGADmUhooBueYbIzYcuQhDwgUgB0IHj2tABEKrYQDlIR9Bys3iYiYrwWVgByqup0worKahr0hbkaXj7QpFLE5KQE0MKG3snJWMTwvFLQACpdUgDy4siQEDbEABZ4sgA8vQA0cNBSAB7EUgSyMADWUvB44n0AfNp9ANqwALor65vb0ABi5ARUwoTQAPwX19CFUi4NC0sJYNqRxGBgD0AJKIPAqFRgLZeDg4NZSYDkDbOaBI%20AtdrYUBjaBwhFIuaPW4bLa7faHOBIFAQU7CFS8QLRKwwWHwxHI1G43gFRmjKDA7w4fBEMiUah0QVVMDCxQIMUQJaKnwZYQuMAbCQvYCKfrdYbqibTOZq5lLR7HTWSqrmXX6npgUj2CCKaAABQ9YGiYIg8wG5uZlpmsxtYztx2OWpwjEqzpwU2EECCyuEZ2zLSqySqgvRmOxpRwACVavUCKapKGzSMI7UrdGmbGnvGU6manUGtB05nxEagsAwCAQLRB1nhUsgvPpx6vYknW0jJgsIFiE0ZUioWcCFIAO6i5kMCXSki%20clbA-H0l8imzCI67LlUgRY60SwkPdSJY-sQf5BK%20xA5MUpBLOcACsNz0C0l7bkepCEPYiCDDesh3ieZL8nMESSDIsift%20u6vP%20O6-uRQSEXIUFwfoQA)

```js
class MyClass{
  constructor() {}
  
  public field: number = 1;

  public printMessage(): void{
    console.log("message")
  }
  public printNumber(i: number): number{
    return i;
  }
}

type TypeOfClassMethod<T, M extends keyof T> = T[M] extends Function ? T[M] : never;

interface ICommand{

    execute(): any;
}

 class Command<F extends keyof MyClass> implements ICommand{
    api: MyClass;

    constructor(
        api: MyClass, 
        private func: TypeOfClassMethod<MyClass, F>, 
        private args:  Parameters<TypeOfClassMethod<MyClass, F>> //
        ) {
        this.api = api;
    }
    
    execute():  ReturnType<TypeOfClassMethod<MyClass, F>>{ 
 // error[1] type ‘TypeOfClassMethod<MyClass, F>’ does not satisfy the constraint ‘(...args: any) => any’.
 // Type ‘Function & MyClass[F]’ is not assignable to type ‘(...args: any) => any’.
        return this.func.call(this.api, ...this.args)
    }
}


let instance = new MyClass();

const command = new Command<"printNumber">(instance, instance.printNumber, [5] );
const wrongCOmmand = new Command<"field">(instance, instance.field, [] );
```

EDIT:
My main problem with the implementation i had is that it gives errors if i have non-function members in a class, I want it to work for other classes that have non-executable members but give me an error if I want to create a command with a member that is not executable.

Basically I want to call this in a wrapper function `callWithRetry` which gets passed a command and it executes it until it succeeds or a certain break criteria are met.

[Take a look here, as an example (TS playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgEp1oBfbbXABwoCMQBLYNABm-AKYgAJgC5ohCgFseYstAC80AIwBudjmjc+gg2X6ESsMVDABzMY1kA3fP0noOuPEQj4QYgHQg+DZ0AEQKVhC2YqEMHmz6hgJCnKbmAHKKyvT8svJKKgx5WSru+rhkYiQUZITQ-Lr6CQnYJPCcYtAAYnUadP4DYGQ2ELJghPBMagB80OPwem0d0ABqYCAUVgA8ACqzGjsA2gDWYvD4wtA7ALqL7Z0A8jwkYGaWJAAW+JIQu-tluEOAAUyPhOPU6qdzpcbrIjiCwddoGIAB4kMSEH7dOoAfmgh3hoM41wANNAgUMwBF0WRfoTEdMkbICcCiaT8ddblgWlglp0KWQqXT-msNtsni83lUvj8-tM9NgzDThGBgJ0AJKIfAKBTjNyYfSosTACjohxzCaNHnYUCQGBanV6rbq4gvQhq6YG3BgTi5aAu0jjNWNb3DUbkykKX4Bt0evS4AiuyjUWh0Dze32yGNBsQk9PQAb+IYjWQCoXO105+X6JhezyffgQIu+9RzX0h+sfRtFsOt4sQeLx5Eo42m+y1-P8S50BtN-uHAAMSLMgfdYgu3Qo7pI-CIE-Knkq1Vq0FnPZGi+u-mA6xAM67c99ZMLZ-nmmucQPCVwzQVWD8JAQquaqtoQYgAO5wEgKAQIwjQ2t4gEEI6mKgRB0AOrqmJ0Cusa5kBeH+KkSqZAUZBkocACsH7aNAAD0dHQPgxzYAxXiul4KGSAATGhkGYXqOGVmuZK4TmRFpCQpHZBRADkpBkLJNH0YxqIdNQYhuCooJkHowhbtQu51EaJrogJmIVsBYg7Pc0x0MhWEyBh2qOZZeE2R00y1ip9TQOB4yATQ0AUBAnSzhCczQFhYGqBA-AKPw4CqEFs6iXUYDQEeZDwFFxofOMjYKGSPCmhF4U3qF-rQEElWfJ0R41IQHliB4DUng5er+CZY6MNgLDQHoiakJlVgUCAgEaN1ZkuYJHWYgw8FYENvgBEEIRTWI5mSPZM3zQwQA)

[Or this one which is based on your first answer's second option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgEp1oBfbbXABwoCMQBLYNABm-AKYgAJgC5ohCgFseYstAC80AIwBudjmjc%20gg2X6ESsMVDABzMY1kA3fP0noOuPEQj4QYgHQg%20DZ0AEQKVhC2YqEMHmz6hgJCnKbmAHKKyvT8svJKKgx5WSru%20rhkYiQUZITQ-Lr6CQnYJPCcYtAAYnUadP4DYGQ2ELJghPBMagB80OPweq3tnQDyPCRgZpYkABb4khAAPAAqsxqY%20gDaAApk%20Jz1dQDWYvD4wtDHALqyxzd3nC%200DEAA8SGJCAdunUAPzQW73aB5MSOFTYFiXF5vD7fPRmcFkYRgYCdACSiHwCgU4zcF1woLEwAo4IccwmjRaWFAkBgFKpNMOpOIG0IJIANHAqns3KDwZCYELSOMSZc1hstlL9kdFSKSdMgQAyaGzfgKTh%20CLmBV86mQsq4MCcXLQHXKsSNDwEYWUai0OgeB1O2Su0ViMUBkz8RxgcEiCii2TbaXh8qR6OxoYjWTXIZgCIEo5J-bTDxMOmeXb8CD%20R38dRzJ2NXCc%20kgxnM%20xFaAAJSqNUIx2WhyLklm5Yqfdq0Er1eE8eA-mAYBAIDoM5rTolA3868zEDiTXRiywfhIjyVofrhDEAHc4EgUBBGB6ud4zwR%20XaNNe7zaaXQzAvcVz11AJUnxTICjICVLgAVi%20BhtGgAB6ZDoHwJ5sFQrxhWgG87kIGxEBWT83G-W9oD-SEAOFN0JUA0D-FECRJBghCkOw0EOmoMQZTIO4yD0bCvVILxSIAJivCiqMkGigLDEC3X8cCMhKaDoEuAByUgyE09iULQrjGXBPiBL0OdRRIfgiGBNsmXBAB1fhdl7ch4DoD9bRkF0ZLLDxKmqKdPJpfwGXszsjywbARLPSoIAoEAzw0MKOyclyqjIdzgshA9ou8XwAiCEI4oSkgGCAA)

Both lack return type when I try to call it inside a function.

```js
function executeCommand < InstanceType > (command: Command < InstanceType > ) {
 // i want to use this in a manner similar to this, in a retry mechanism, but in this case I lose the returnType
  return command.execute()
}

const result = executeCommand(command); // result will have a return type of any
```

UPDATE:
I got it to work how I wanted it, thank you so much for the help!
[here is the solution in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=52&ssc=27&pln=51&pc=99#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgEp1oBfbbXABwoCMQBLYNABm-AKYgAJgC5ohCgFseYstAC80AIwBudjmjc%20gg2X6ESsMVDABzMY1kA3fP0noOuPEQj4QYgHQg%20DZ0AEQKVhC2YqEMHmz6hgJCnKbmAHKKyvT8svJKKgx5WSru%20rhkYiQUZITQ-Lr6CQnYJPCcYtAAYnUadP4DYGQ2ELJghPBMagB80OPweq3tnQDyPCRgZpYkABb4khAAPAAqsxqY%20gDaAApk%20Jz1dQDWYvD4wtDHALqyxzd3nC%200DEAA8SGJCAdunUAPzQW73aB5MSOFTYFiXF5vD7fPRmcFkYRgYCdACSiHwCgU4zcF1woLEwAo4IccwmjRaWFAkBgFKpNMOpOIG0IJIANHAqns3KDwZCYELSOMSZc1hstlL9kdFSKSdMgQAyaGzfgKTh%20CLmBV86mQsq4MCcXLQHXKsSNDwEYWUai0OgeB1O2Su0ViMUBkz8RxgcEiCii2TbaXh8qR6OxoYjWTXIZgCIEo5J-bTDxMOmeXb8CD%20R38dRzJ2NXCc%20kgxnM%20xFaAAJSqNUIx2WhyLklm5Yqfdq0Er1eE8eA-mAYBAIDoM5rTolA3868zEDiTXRiywfhIjyVofrhDEAHc4EgUBBGB6ud4zwR%20XaNNe7zaaXQzAvcVz11AJUnxTICjICVLgAVi%20BhtGgAB6ZDoHwJ5sC9UgvE-SRNCvW9oD-SEAOFN0JUA0D-HA8xLGsOwYIQpDUPQzCsFY7CzxvO5CBsRAVjwwjf0pW1JDIoCwxAt1-FECRJCYxCULQ0EOmoMQZTIO4yD0Ti31wsSACZhOI0T-yoijpNDGi0hISDshggByUgyEc5jlOBEE1PBTTtKw-TKggCgQBIAiNA-MT-AZJkWUQvQ51FEh%20CITz23BAB1fhdl7ch4EFcjQwlEdPLlKEQxVNVNkIEdtQKvVDWNOgIppWQSMkfLJKKzVRzLDxKmqKdmshKK2xizsjywfzhWgQLgrPDRoo7TLsqqMh4CaszIQPLiZqsObNGMhbRqWrKdhytaNrwzQDymnw-ECYI6FmkKGCAA)

Comment: Why do you want to make it work with non methods, I mean ` instance.field` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I have should have made it more clear, I do not want to make it work with non-methods, I want it to work with classes that have non-methods in them. Like if i want to use it for non-method members it should give me an error, but right now it gives me an error for every member of the class that has non-methods. But if I use a class that only has executables it gives no errors.
Does that make sense?

Comment: please take a look on my answer, if it meets your requirements I will add an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation/description is in comments**

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() { }

  public field: number = 1;

  public printMessage(): void {
    console.log("message")
  }
  public printNumber(i: number): number {
    return i;
  }
}

// Base type for any function/method
type Fn = (...args: any) => any

// Obtain union of all values
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

/**
 * Converts object to dictionary where
 *  keys are just object keys
 *  values are a tuples where 
 * 
 *    first element is key value
 *    second element is an array of arguments
 * 
 *      if first element is not a method,
 *      second element will be empty array
 */
type ObtainMethods<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends Fn ? [T[Prop], Parameters<T[Prop]>] : [T[Prop], []]
}
{
  //   type Test = {
  //     field: [number, []];
  //     printMessage: [() => void, []];
  //     printNumber: [(i: number) => number, [i: number]];
  // }
  type Test = ObtainMethods<MyClass>
}

/**
 * Params obtains a union of all object values
 * Since we have a union of tuples, we can use it
 * for typing rest parameters
 */
type Params<T> = Values<ObtainMethods<T>>
{
  // | [[number, []], []] 
  // | [[() => void, []], []]
  // | [[(i: number) => number, [i: number]], []]
  type Test = Params<ObtainMethods<MyClass>>
}

interface ICommand {
  execute(): any;
}


class Command<Instance>{
  api: Instance;
  args: Params<Instance>

  constructor(
    api: Instance,
    ...args: Params<Instance>
  ) {
    this.api = api;
    this.args = args
  }

  execute() {
    if (this.args[0] instanceof Function) {
      return this.args[0].call(this.api, ...this.args)
    }
  }
}


let instance = new MyClass();

const command = new Command(instance, instance.printNumber, [5]); // ok
const command2 = new Command(instance, instance.printNumber, ['str']); // expected error

const wrongCOmmand1 = new Command(instance, instance.field, []); // ok
const wrongCOmmand2 = new Command(instance, instance.field, []); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoa1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgEp1oBfbbXABwoCMQBLYNABm-AKYgAJgC5ohCgFseYstAC80AIwBudjmjc+gg2X6ESsMVDABzMY1kA3fP0noOuPEQj4QYgHQg+DZ0AEQKVhC2YqEMHmz6hgJCnKbmAHKKyvT8svJKKgx5WSru+rhkYiQUZITQ-Lr6CQnYJPCcYtAAYnUadP4DYGQ2ELJghPBMagB80OPwem0d0ABqYCAUVgA8ACqzGjsA2gDWYvD4wtA7ALp6APQAVA8cD9CIRI4qJDD4PABWYmo0Bo0EkghI-CIQ3g0AA7gALFRiF64U7wGBDTp-CikaC-AFAtEQFHQRzrTYYypzYEUTh+GAIpHQFEk3CiMi4iRiCLmeowNGk8nInCvTwQQFENxcnkkPlzOpDMhgGEXObDRRiczEkXMnWeXD8S7szl+GVywj4WVgaAREjw-CSAA0rLFEsIUtNmtlsP4IBA0GU0G5nDaaqVCxFd1a7U6AHkeCQwGZLHaHRBdvsyrhDgAFMj4Tj1Opo1U3WRHPMF65BgAeJE1khgPWgAH5oIcK-nONdHdAc0MwLaVOnO1XptXZB3c12e+3rrcsAlMPo7ndPEtOjsrLKNMvcKv9SJxFJJ-lsr3DvPGvu1-rUmYLJFopPGOpZs5XBerx4D3e0iRMgKMgX1yOQSjIKZZjPFQL1A6CyG-Fc1wSXANyubd1GgeNE2TKp7UbLYEGQSAIGmbAWiwR5nh1fslQUH4EyTYhqQoQhITqVV1n9fFAVlMkNisFEAGUzGATpYU6eEwE+Fi2KIPFLmqOkrF7CS8HGaAcU6fgSBRYRaGBdozBsaBKlxTgByHDkXijLA0NowcR0zNYBPTbCmJTfCnLIrA92gA8AB920OeCv1nS9qx-NcgsOQ5XxmUkXCdOdwvnKLoBiuK4PAyCwKA2DiiA+cwo8NCt1xDQHPorZ3Nw1MCKIlBSJ8iiHxUYQwDE6AAEl3gUBRxjcPyxBrQEKHrBx5XgRoKOwUASLefB+sGrZuuIRNCDE6Y-LAThQLW0hxjE681RGWQqvTA6Nq2vRcAIdbKGoWg6A8XBdv29ajrEZ1ymgAZ-CGM6+0sy7Ps2sQfNwJg-NQ+F+AgAG9sw96Tth+GAeGGANEB7VcAo3ARrGibode+pLjoO10Zxw4AAZqzMQ7wdVLpWOodiSd+ioqhqOpKYR6m6f8YAuIpuH+b23t-r5jGRjiX6UNYci9GwPxZQZ67Og0QgxFhOAkCaxhGjm7xZQIZb3Uw7Xdb6gb3TodWvt7B3wf8e8MnAi8AFZrgYbR-LXfBjmN9avHNyQACZLZ1xaw-tsGxKd+OAjdgCPfbAByUgyHTn2-YPEaOmoMQpTIfMyD0e7cVhfNCBsRBYzDzQo+tpbbckOPGYTotO4CUQJGSy9ff9vEg6wSvvRruuG7byOtejm3Bo7jXE57-w+6kL8h4PQOgA)

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking of your answer i got it to work how i wanted it to, update in my answer. Thank you so much for the help, you are a genius :D

Comment: @Komi you are welcome. I will ad an explanation

Comment: @Komi added comments to type utils. Let me know if you have further questions